# PyDantic setter callbacks

Tags: python, pydantic

What I'm trying to achieve is a functionality where I can add and remove callbacks from a PyDantic (>2.0) model.

With the standard Python dictionary, it would look something like this

```py
class DictionaryWithCallbacks(dict):
    """
    A standard Python dictionary with support for callbacks that get executed when a key is set

    The callable accepts three arguments:
     - The dictionary itself
     - The key that is about to be set
     - The value that is about to be set

    This means that the callback has the current state of the dictionary, plus the new key and value that are about to
    be set, allowing delta calculations between the state and new value. The value is set only after the callback is
    executed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._callbacks = defaultdict(list)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """
        Set item and call callbacks

        :param key: Key to set
        :param value: Value to set
        :return: None
        """
        for callback in self._callbacks[key]:
            callback(self, key, value)
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def register_set_callback(self, key, callback: t.Callable[['DictionaryWithCallbacks', str, object], None]):
        """
        Register callback for key

        :param key: Key
        :param callback: Callback
        :return: None
        """

        self._callbacks[key].append(callback)

    def unregister_set_callback(self, key, callback: t.Callable[['DictionaryWithCallbacks', str, object], None]):
        """
        Unregister callback for key

        :param key: Key
        :param callback: Callback
        :return: None
        """
        with suppress(ValueError):
            self._callbacks[key].remove(callback)
```

How can I achieve something similar in PyDantic?

Comment: Are you talking about [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)? This seems entirely unrelated to Pydantic.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg , it is related to PyDantic, as I know how to achieve this with "vanilla" Python, but I want to replicate this using PyDantic models

Comment: And what were the problems that you encountered, when you tried to apply your knowledge to a concrete Pydantic model? Did anything unexpected happen?